# Having troubles for proving that for ever prime $p$ and for every positive integer $n$ there is a field having $p^n$ elements

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

I have a problem justifying a step on Rotman's proof of the following theorem:

> For every prime $p$ and every positive integer $n$ there exists a field having exactly $p^{n}$ elements.

(Rotman, *Galois Theory*, 2nd Edition, p. 36).

Let me sketch the beginning of the proof:

What we do is to define the polynomial
$$g(x)=x^{q}-x \in \mathbb{Z}[x], \hspace{0.7cm} \text{where} \hspace{0.2cm} q = p^n,$$
and to consider a field $E$ that contais $\mathbb{Z}_{p}$ as a subfield and all the roots of $g$. Since $\mathbb{Z}_{p} \subseteq E$, it's clear that the characteristic of the field $E$ is $p$. Then,

$$(\forall a, b \in E)(\forall k \in \mathbb{Z}^{+}): \hspace{0.3cm} (a+b)^{p^k}=a^{p^k} +b ^{p^k}.$$

Let $F \subseteq E$ be the set of roots of the polynomial $g(x)$. Noticing that $(g, g')=1$ we infer that $g$ has no repeted roots, i.e. that $ |F|= q = p^n$.
If we show that the set $F$ is a field we are done, and we try to prove this by showing that $F$ us a subfield of $E$.

---

I have no problems following the argument above, but when trying to justify that
$$\forall a, b \in F: \hspace{0.3cm} a-b \in F .$$

If $a, b \in F$, then $a^q=a$ and $b^q=b$; therefore,
$$(a-b)^{q}= (a+ (-b)) ^{q} = (a+ (-b))^{p^n} = a ^{p^n}+ (-b)^{p^n} = a ^{p^n} + 
(-1 \cdot b)^{p^n} = a ^{p^n} + (-1)^{p^n}b ^{p^n} = a^q + (-1)^q b^q; $$

$$(a-b)^{q}= a + (-1)^q b.$$

In general, in a ring $R$, if $l \in \mathbb{Z}^{+}$,
$$(-1)^{l}= 1 \hspace{0.2 cm} \text{if} \hspace{0.1cm} l \hspace{0.1cm} \text{is even}, \hspace{0.5 cm} (-1)^{l}= -1 \hspace{0.2 cm} \text{if} \hspace{0.1cm} l \hspace{0.1cm} \text{is odd}.$$

Now, if the prime $p$ in question is not 2, then $p$ is odd and so $q=p^n$ is odd, thus we get that  $(a-b)^{q}= a - b$, as desired.

---

**My question is:** What happens if the prime $p$ is 2? In this case, q is even; therefore $(a-b)^{q}= a^{q} + b^{q},$
and we can not conclude that $a-b \in F$.

Thank you in advance for your feedback.

Comment: When $p=2$, then $a+b=a-b$ because $x=-x$ for all $x$ (also, $1\equiv -1\pmod{2}$).

Comment: Now I remember why one should be careful when the characteristic of the field is 2 :-) thank you so much for your comment @ArturoMagidin !